# assertValue doesn't work on select boxes with the Selenium IDE Firefox plugin

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium IDE in Firefox to build test cases.

When I right-click on a select box and choose "Show All Available Commands," `assertValue` is always grayed out. With text boxes and option boxes, I can use `assertValue` to make sure that a specific value is set. Why is this functionality not available for select boxes? Or is there a trick needed to make Selenium IDE let me user `assertValue` on an HTML select box?

If you want a concrete example, try the following:

1. Start a new Selenium IDE Test Case.
2. Open http://www.google.com/advanced_search
3. Near the bottom of the page, there is an HTML select box for "Language" which defaults to "Any Language." Right-Click on "Any Language" and go to "Show All Available Commands," and `assertValue` will be grayed out. Why can't I use `assertValue` on this select box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because it's not available from "Show All Available Commands" does not necessarily mean you'll not be able to use it.  Add a command to the IDE and select it in the sequence of operations in your test (i.e. from the "Table" view not the "Source" view).  Now you'll see the "Command", "Target" and "Value" for your selected operation; just change the command to the one you require.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I sorted that out, add manually new command in the IDE:

```
Command: assertSelectedValue
Target: id=countrySelect
Value: Switzerland
```

Comment: Using 'assertSelectedValue' will give an integer ID of the option, not its label value 'Switzerland'. Thus, 'assertSelectedLabel' is a better fit here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `assertValue` on a dropdown select because select tag has only options, not the value attribute.

You can click on the languages dropdown and select from the options.

Below is the code for selecting a value from the dropdown list in IDE for the mentioned site.

```
open /advanced_search
click //option[@value='lang_el']
select lr label=French
```